# Trying to use same file within two functions, but unable to see output from both functions?

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to run the following code. But I don't get an output for my call to term_double_score() function. I would really appreciate any help as to why this is happening and how to see the output for both the function calls?

```
  def term_double_score(sent_file):
    scores_double = {} # initialize an empty dictionary with double phrases
    for line in sent_file:
        term, score  = line.split("\t")  # The file is tab-delimited. 
        if " " in term: 
            scores_double[term] = int(score)
    print "Len_double:",len(scores_double.items())



def term_single_score(sent_file):
    scores_single = {} # initialize an empty dictionary with single phrases
    for line in sent_file:
        term, score  = line.split("\t")  # The file is tab-delimited. 
        scores_single[term] = int(score) 
    print "Len_single:",len(scores_single.items()) 


sent_file = open("some.txt")


term_single_score(sent_file)
term_double_score(sent_file)
```

Comment: Because once you've read through the lines in `term_single_score`, the file's "read head" is at the end of the file.

Comment: Oh okay..so how can I read it again in another function. Do I have to close it and open again in the function where I want to use it again?

Comment: You can "rewind" with `sent_file.seek(0)` - see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects

Answer (score 0):

1. In @jonrsharpe's solution, the code reads and processes the file once, for `single_score`. Before the second processing with `double_score`, reset the file pointer with `sent_file.seek(0)` so the code can re-read the file again.
2. The following solution reads the entire file in and buffers it. `Single_score` is run based on the copy of the file's data.  Then `double_score` is run on the copy again.

The latter solution is good if the file is small; the system has enough memory to hold it in memory.  For immense files, solution #1 is superior.

### source

```
def term_double_score(sent_file):
    scores_double = {} # initialize an empty dictionary with double phrases
    for line in sent_file:
        term, score  = line.split("\t")  # The file is tab-delimited. 
        if " " in term: 
            scores_double[term] = int(score)
    print "Len_double:",len(scores_double.items())



def term_single_score(sent_file):
    scores_single = {} # initialize an empty dictionary with single phrases
    for line in sent_file:
        term, score  = line.split("\t")  # The file is tab-delimited. 
        scores_single[term] = int(score) 
    print "Len_single:",len(scores_single.items()) 


# read file and buffer it
sent_file = list( open('zoot.dat') )

term_single_score(sent_file)
term_double_score(sent_file)
```